# c programming making phone book input output and sorting

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a phone book.

My first problem is when I input the phone number for the second time the first phone number get affected by the second name, look like this :

[image]

There is an additional problem with sorting strings. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct contact {
    char name[29];
    char number[11];
};

int main() {
    struct contact contact[100];
    int menu;
    int n = 0;
    int i, j, flag_1, flag_2, flag_3, flag_4, loop;
    char temp[29];

    do {
        loop = 0;
        printf("Phone Book\n");
        printf("==========\n");
        printf("1. Add New Contact\n");
        printf("2. View List Contact\n");
        printf("3. Search Contact\n");
        printf("4. Delete Contact\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n");
        printf("choose menu: ");
        scanf("%d", &menu); 
        system("cls");

        switch (menu) {
        case 1:

            printf("Add New Contact\n");
            do {
                flag_1 = flag_2 = 1;
                printf("Input name [1..30 char]: ");
                scanf(" %[^\n]", contact[n].name); 

                if (strlen(contact[n].name) > 30) {
                    printf("Length of name should be between 1 and 30 characters.\n");
                    flag_1 = 0;
                }

                if (!isalpha(contact[n].name[0])) {
                    printf("First letter of name should be an alphabet (A-Z od a-z).\n");
                    flag_1 = 0;
                }

            } while (flag_1 == 0 || flag_2 == 0);

            do {
                flag_3 = flag_4 = 1;
                printf("Input phone number [6..12 digits]: ");
                scanf("%s", contact[n].number); 

                if (strlen(contact[n].number) < 6 || strlen(contact[n].number) > 12) {
                    printf("Length of phone numbers should be between 6 and 12 digits.\n");
                    flag_3 = 0;
                }

                for (i = 0; i < strlen(contact[n].number); i++) {
                    if (!isdigit(contact[n].number[i])) {
                        flag_4 = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (flag_4 == 0) {
                    printf("Phone numbers should only contain digits (0-9).\n");
                }
            } while (flag_3 == 0 || flag_4 == 0);

            printf("\n");
            printf("New contact successfully added!\n\n");
            printf("Name : %s\n", contact[n].name);
            printf("Number : %s\n\n", contact[n].number);
            printf("Press Enter to continue...");
            n++;
            getchar();
            getchar();
            system("cls");
            loop = 0;
            break;


        case 2:
            printf("View List Contact\n\n");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
                    if (strcmp(contact[j].name, contact[j + 1].name) > 0) {
                        strcpy(temp, contact[j].name);
                        strcpy(contact[j].name, contact[j + 1].name);
                        strcpy(contact[j + 1].name, temp);

                        strcpy(temp, contact[j].number);
                        strcpy(contact[j].number, contact[j + 1].number);
                        strcpy(contact[j + 1].number, temp);

                    }
                }
            }
            printf("     # Name                            Phone Number\n");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                printf("    %d %s                 %s\n", i + 1, contact[i].name, contact[i].number);
            }

            getchar();
            getchar();
            system("cls");
            loop = 0;
            break;
        }

    } while (loop == 0);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone help me to solve my problems?

P.S.: Apologies for my bad English.

Comment: `char number[11];` is small.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, and don't put to statements in a single line, it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: To expand on the `number[11]` comment: When you put an 11 digit number into that field, there is no room for the string terminator. That shows when you print it - the string isn't terminated and the printing continues with some other field.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY has the right point. number[11] has an 11-digit number in it, and doesn't leave any room for trailing null the all C strings need. So the output will continue with the characters in the 'name' member of the next array entry.

Comment: I think you have confused the rules about strings - an eleven element array of char can hold a ten - not twelve - character string. (Because it needs a terminating zero.)

Comment: Side note: don't name things "flag"; the name contains no information whatsoever. It's like naming an `int` "integer" or a `struct` "structure". It's also much easier to spot accidental use of the wrong flag if you give them useful names (bug hint).

Comment: Don' post images of text!

Answer (score 3):

As present in the comments, the problem is a overflow on your read, you're reading outside of the space reserved for `char number[11]`, therefore reading until the next '\0', that in this case is the one present in `char name[29]`.

In memory the struct go in the following form:

```
-----------------------
| name[0]    |
|  ...       |  
| name[29]   |   this is the X element of contact[100]
| number[0]  |
|  ...       |
| number[11] |
-----------------------
| name[0]    |
|  ...       |  
| name[29]   |    this is the X+1 element of contact[100]
| number[0]  |   
|  ...       |
| number[11] |
-----------------------
```

To fix it you should increase the size of your `char number[11]` to `char number[12]` and assign (always) the '\0' by yourself to the last position.

`number[11] = '\0';`

And you should do the same with the `name`. Its a good pratice, specifying a maximal length to `scanf`.

```
scanf("%3s", string); -- only reads 3 caracter from the input.
```

Edit: added info of how to fix it.

Comment: How does this solve his problem? What should he do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Few remarks regarding your code:

1.**Make a code flowchart** with brief comments explaining code structure. This will help you reduce you code complexity and volume by skipping possible code duplicates, converting multiply used code into functions or removing redundant lines.

2.It would be much easier for you to manage your code and detect possible errors if you **break it into small functions that perform a simple task**. For example, you could put all the printed messages in the beginning into a single function, like so:

```
void promt_message (void) {

    printf("Phone Book\n");
    printf("==========\n");
    printf("1. Add New Contact\n");
    printf("2. View List Contact\n");
    printf("3. Search Contact\n");
    printf("4. Delete Contact\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n");
    printf("choose menu: ");
    scanf("%d", &menu); 
    system("cls");

}
```

and then replace all these lines in your `main()` with a single: `promt_message ();`. This could be done for all of the different branches in your `switch` statement, i.e. define different functions that handle the different situations and test them separately to see if they perform the wanted tasks.

3.**Add comments and use meaningful variable names**. This will help any reader (including you) to understand your code.

4.Few **obvious bugs**:

when you define a string you should consider it's additional termination character (`'\0'`), in your case `char number[11]` must be of size `12` if you want to store a 11-digit phone number. For more information just search for *"use of C-style strings"*, or take a look at this [C-style string article](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/66-c-style-strings/), for example.